Water Layer - Lake - QuickOSM - missing
Use : Qgis - newest release
OpenStreetMaps
QuickOSM - newest release
In the past when I was making maps I could find a layer called "(Key) Water" called "(Value) Lake", but I can't do that anymore.
Where in QuickOSM should I look to be able to create a layer for lakes? (See the picture. )
Have already searched under the following KEY: Water, Natural,


https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:natural
